# Does mark.js work in a Greasemonkey/Tampermonkey user script?

Tags: javascript, greasemonkey, tampermonkey, mark.js

I have this in the Tampermonkey script header section:

```
// @require      https://raw.githubusercontent.com/julmot/mark.js/master/dist/mark.js
```

My marking instance:

```
   for (var i=0; i<slotValuesRows.length; i++) {
     let targetToMark = new Mark(slotValuesRows[i]);
     targetToMark.mark(["e"],
     {"element": "span",
      "className": "highlight",
      "accuracy": "exactly"});
   }
```

The "e" do not get highlighted and the tab freezes on page load.

I am a beginner, but am suspecting mark.js just does not work with userscripts.

Is that assumption correct?

Comment: The problem sounds like an infinite loop. Are you using MutationObserver? Or maybe getElementsByTagName('span')? It would grow automatically every time you add a span element. Show us more of the code.

Comment: @wOxxOm You were right of course my loop is broken: WAS: 0<slotValuesRows.length SHOULD BE of course: i<slotValuesRows.length Thanks, I corrected the question.

Answer (score 0):

With the help of the documentation [here](https://markjs.io/) > 4.2 and @wOxxOm input above, I was able to fix my loop and highlight all "[" in the target elements. Example:

```
for (var i=0; i<slotValuesRows.length; i++) {
  let targetToMark = new Mark(slotValuesRows[i]);
  targetToMark.mark("[");
}
```

Summarizing and answering question: Turns out you can add

```
// @require      https://raw.githubusercontent.com/julmot/mark.js/master/dist/mark.js
```

to your Greasemonkey/Tampermonkey script and use mark.js.
Hope this helps others.